# What happens after getting max value of map object in Python

Tags: python

```py
nums = map(int, input().split())
if max(nums)** 2 == next(nums)**2 + next(nums)**2:
  print(True)
```

Hi. I found out that when `next(nums)` is executed, `stopIteration` is raised.
I thought **only the max value of `nums`** would be removed from `nums` after `max(nums)` was executed.
But are **all the values of `nums`** removed after `max` function is executed? Looking forward to help! Thanks

Comment: In order for *max* to fulfil its functionality it has to iterate over the *map* object. By the time you try to invoke *next* the iterator has already been exhausted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values are removed, since you are running through the entire iterator (all values) to find the `max` value. Which then removes all the values.

Ex:

```
>>> it = iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> max(it)
3
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    next(it)
StopIteration
>>>
```

The reason for this is because in order to find the maximum value, you need to loop through and use all the values in the iterator.